# How to parallelize an sql insertion using python?

Tags: python, sql-server, parallel-processing, sqlalchemy

Using the sqlalchemy package, I can access to my sql server through this engine :

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('''DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
                                    SERVER=SERVER_NAME;
                                    DATABASE=DATABASE_NAME;
                                    TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;''')

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params,case_sensitive=False)
```

I can insert my dataframe df into a specific sql table with this code :

```
df.to_sql(name = table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

However, my dataframe has a lot of rows and consequently, the insertion takes a long time to complete. Do you know please if it is possible to parallelize this insertion ?

Comment: SQL Server suupports both row-by-row inserts and bulk loading.  Bulk Loading is much faster if sqlalchemy supports it.  If not, you might try Spark.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft from looking at pandas `to_sql` it suggests that it will _default_ to bulk uploads, and chunking is optional. That said, for postgres, they had to implement [and additional method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-sql-method) to use `copy` because the python binding just translated `executemany` to single transactions. I don't know whether there might be a similar issue for SQL Server (I don't use it)?